# I am making a stopwatch using python but not a normal stopwatch

Tags: append, shutdown

I am making a stopwatch using python but not a normal when we start our laptop the stopwatch get started and when we shutdown it the total time get appended to list named total time. but i ran into a problem I don't know how to append the total time when the windows gets shutdown. please help me out.

I dont know anything what to do. please help me out.